# Standalone program for accessing and developing in Linux in web browser

Tags: linux, ssh, ide, gdb

Is there any software working like this?

- Runs as a standalone program. No install is needed. Thus, can be used as an [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) module.
- After running the program in a remote Linux machine, I can open up a web browser, then open a web page provided by the program. The program provides features similar to file explorer, IDE-level code editor, debugger, etc. In terms of debugger, there is already similar one; [gdbgui](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui).

There is another way such as Gnome, KDE or X11. However, these requires much packages to be installed. I don't want they be installed, because my Linux machines are kept to be small and secure.

Comment: Off-topic since asking for resources.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider having some terminal emulator running inside a browser. Such things exist, e.g. [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) has [oterm](https://www.coralbits.com/oterm/) as an example application. Then you can do all the things that a command line interface thru a unix shell provides (of course, you won't be able to run GUI applications, e.g. [X11 clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol) such as GTK or Qt applications).

You could also consider some [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) like stuff.

Notice that you don't need to have a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) on a remote Linux machine. Most of them (e.g. internet servers) have only command line interface.

Learn more about [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System): you could have an X11 server on your laptop (e.g. under Windows if so needed) and run remotely X11 clients (that is GUI applications) with `ssh -X` on your remote Linux system.

> However, these requires much packages to be installed. I don't want they be installed, because my Linux machines are kept to be small and secure.

I don't understand that requirement. On my VPS, running in some OVH datacenter, I do have X11 client applications (notably [`emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)). I don't believe that lowers the security of my system, and the disk space consumption for X11 applications and libraries is small enough these days. And of course I use standard commands (like [cp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html), [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html), [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html), [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), [less(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html), [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html), [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) ....) to manage files. Any graphical file manager is useless (and I never use them, while using Unix since 1986)

You really should learn how to use the command line on Linux. It is incredibly powerful.